# Why I'm getting empty string when trying to get a prefab asset path?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 private void ModifyPrefab(GameObject child)
    {
        var mostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(child);

        // Get the Prefab Asset root GameObject and its asset path.
        string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(mostPrefabInstanceRoot);

        // Load the contents of the Prefab Asset.
        GameObject contentsRoot = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(assetPath);

        // Modify Prefab contents.
        DestroyImmediate(child);

        // Save contents back to Prefab Asset and unload contents.
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(contentsRoot, assetPath);
        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(contentsRoot);
    }
```

assetPath is empty ""

When running the first mostPrefabInstanceRoot is : "Room_Large_Windows_Part_03 (UnityEngine.GameObject)"

[image: First mostPrefabInstanceRoot]

And in the editor this object is a prefab :

[image: The prefab in hierarchy]

Then when doing on the prefab right click and Select Prefab Asset it's getting to this :

[image: The prefab asset]

But in the script the string return ""

I can't figure out why it returns empty string ?

Edit this is my completed script now :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsReplace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabToInit;

    // Note your method should probably return something
    public void UpdateOrAddShaderPrefabToDoors()
    {
        GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Left");
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Right");

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        allDoors.ForEach(gameObject =>
        {
            Transform childTransform = gameObject.transform.Find("DoorShieldFXLocked Variant");
            GameObject child = childTransform?.gameObject;
            Debug.Log($"Child exist: {child != null}, Name of child: {child?.name}");
            if (child != null)
            {
                ModifyPrefab(child);
            }
        });
    }

    private void ModifyPrefab(GameObject child)
    {
        var mostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(child);

        // Get the Prefab Asset root GameObject and its asset path.
        string assetPath = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(mostPrefabInstanceRoot);

        // Load the contents of the Prefab Asset.
        GameObject contentsRoot = PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents(assetPath);

        // Modify Prefab contents.
        DestroyImmediate(child);

        // Save contents back to Prefab Asset and unload contents.
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(contentsRoot, assetPath);
        PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents(mostPrefabInstanceRoot);
    }
}
```

But still getting exception in editor when trying to destroy the child :

InvalidOperationException: Destroying a GameObject inside a Prefab instance is not allowed.

The idea is to open the child prefab it's belong to destroy the child and then save and close the prefab like doing Overrides > Apply Changes in the editor but from the script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `mostPrefabInstanceRoot` is not an asset, and that makes sense since it's an instance of the prefab. Use `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot` instead of `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath`.

```cs
string assetPath = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(mostPrefabInstanceRoot);
```

Also, in order for your edit to work, you probably want to save `mostPrefabInstanceRoot` instead of `contentRoot`, since `contentRoot` will be unchanged by deleting the child.

Comment: I'm getting exception in the editor : InvalidOperationException: Destroying a GameObject inside a Prefab instance is not allowed.

Comment: I edited my question added my completed script and what I'm trying to do.